# Could not load Tomcat 9.0 Server in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

When I try to add Tomcat 9.0 to Eclipse (Define a New Server > Tomcat v9.0 Server), I get: *Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf*.

Interestingly, I do see that exact directory on the file system. I installed Tomcat 9 using the installer (.exe), so that's the default location where it ended up. Is there some reason why Eclipse would not be able to recognize it?

[image]

I was able to define a Tomcat 8.0 server with no issues. I had downloaded the Tomcat 8 binary rather than using the installer.

Comment: Sounds like a file/folder permission problem.

Comment: Did you remove the Tomcat installation and try again? Or use the zip, instead.

Comment: I tried both. It seems ok now, but I'm still confused. Seemed to intermittently give the above error - whether using the Tomcat installation or the binary from the zip.